# SSL Peer Certificate Untrusted in SAP

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, abap, sap-basis

I have a requirement of getting data from Non SAP system in one server to SAP Z table in other server. For that I created a https service in non SAP sytem that give me desired data. Now I am trying to consume that service through ABAP Code by creating Http object by URL ('https://host:port/prefixpath') , there On recieving I am getting error as SSL PEER CERT UNTRUSTED .
Although I have importe SSL certificate and activate https service.

Comment: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3161319 maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Import the certificate in STRUSTSSO2, then create a HTTP destination in SM59 for your service. Assign the client certificate there. Test the connection in SM59.

If it doesn't work, talk to your BASIS people. It's a very common setup for them.

Once the connection is successful, write your ABAP program using the destination.